# C# & MS Access - SQL for Create Table, Column and add values at the start of the app

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I am trying to develop a project with C# and a MS Access database, the project has a table named `Employee`. I created all the DB, table, attributes on MS Access but I want to check the database if exist or not and check the tables if exist or not and also check the attributes if exist or not and create the DB, table and add the values if lack of anyone.

So I created a method and try to check this situations. But, in my code there is some method to get the values to datagridview from the database, if I delete my database file, I get errors in the datagridview or any of this type can not find the db. I called my method at the very top.

```
Table name --> Employee - columns (Name, Surname). 
Second Table --> Department - column (Department_Name) This table has to come with two values; Engineering and Accountant.
```

Calling the method to check:

```
public Form1()
{
    checkDB();
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

My code to check the DB:

```
static void checkDB()
{
    try
    {
        OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source= Employee.accdb");
        myConnection.Open();

        OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand();
        myCommand.Connection = myConnection;

        myCommand.CommandText = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXIST [Employee] + 
                                 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST 'Employee' [ID] Counter Primary Key,
                        [FirstName] Text, [LastName] Text +  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST 'Department' 
                        [ID] Counter Primary Key, [Department_Name] Text + insert if not exist into 
                        Department(Department_Name) values('Engineer , Accountant ') ";
        // Added new lines to read it easily

        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        myCommand.Connection.Close();
    }
    catch(OleDbException e)
    {  
        // err.message
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome @daprog, what is the error you get

Comment: You can't use CREATE DATABASE to create an accdb file on disk. The file needs to already exist. This is a big difference between a file-based database and a server-based database. Frankly though, I would say Access is mostly unsuitable as a backend for another application - that's not really the purpose it was designed for. If you want a simple file-based database for your desktop app, maybe consider SQLite. (At least that way as well, the users of your application won't require an Office license which includes Access).

Comment: The error is could not found file - because there is no file I can not create it. @Ajay2707

Comment: I have used Access as an application backend, and I would recommend using just about anything else. There are more appropriate embedded database engines, like SQL Lite, SQL CE, or just plain files on disk for that matter.

Comment: @ADyson - AFAIK an Office license is not strictly required to use the Access Database Engine, although it is very convenient to have a copy of Access available for maintenance, troubleshooting, etc.

Comment: The application is 100% ready. Just this step has some errors. If this is the only way so I can just copy a blank file to the folders. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access SQL does not support `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` so we need to check for the existence of the table ourselves:

```cs
string tableName = "team";
DataTable dt = myConnection.GetSchema("Tables", new string[] { null, null, tableName });
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Table already exists.");
} 
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("We need to CREATE TABLE");
}
```

Also, as mentioned in the comments to the question, Access SQL does not support `CREATE DATABASE` at all, so we need to use ADOX

```cs
var myConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
try
{
    myConnection.Open();
    Console.WriteLine("Database already existed.");
}
catch
{
    var cat = new ADOX.Catalog();
    cat.Create(connectionString);
    Console.WriteLine("Database created.");
    myConnection.Open();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

An Access database file may be well suited for this and doesn't require any purchased license.

The, by a factor, simplest method, is to include an empty database file in your project. Then, if none is present, copy this to the user's folder and establish the connection.